# Debugging USB serial disconnection on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, usb

On one of my raspberry pis (Raspbian OS) with a USB serial device connected, there is periodic disconnection of the serial device while still being registered as a USB device.

`lsusb` returns a valid Bus Device entry, but there is no corresponding `/dev/serial/` entry.

The only way to fix this issue is rebooting the pi, which I'd like to avoid.

I'd love some ideas on how I can debug USB serial connections on a Raspberry Pi Linux platform, or methods to reset the serial connection without requiring a reboot.

We tried:

- Tracking `udevadm monitor` to see USB related events. This is what is seen where we catch a serial disconnection / reconnection happening:

```
KERNEL[65879.184887] remove   /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/tty/ttyACM1 (tty)
KERNEL[65879.185179] remove   /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[65879.185389] remove   /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[65879.185728] remove   /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.2 (usb)
KERNEL[65879.186275] remove   /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [65879.193792] remove   /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [65879.197016] remove   /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/tty/ttyACM1 (tty)
UDEV  [65879.197414] remove   /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [65879.203665] remove   /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [65879.205795] remove   /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3 (usb)

==> /var/log/messages <==
Jan 20 18:36:42 rpi4161a-172-101 kernel: [65879.307684] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 12

==> /var/log/syslog <==
Jan 20 18:36:42 rpi4161a-172-101 kernel: [65879.307684] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 12
KERNEL[65880.121912] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3 (usb)
KERNEL[65880.122424] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[65880.125157] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/tty/ttyACM0 (tty)
KERNEL[65880.125702] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[65880.126324] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [65880.158159] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [65880.167588] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [65880.168004] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [65880.169128] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [65880.177534] add      /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/tty/ttyACM0 (tty)

==> /var/log/messages <==
Jan 20 18:36:43 rpi4161a-172-101 kernel: [65880.244987] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=****, idProduct=****, bcdDevice= 1.00
Jan 20 18:36:43 rpi4161a-172-101 kernel: [65880.245001] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan 20 18:36:43 rpi4161a-172-101 kernel: [65880.245010] usb 1-1.3: Product: J-Link Pro OB
Jan 20 18:36:43 rpi4161a-172-101 kernel: [65880.245020] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: ****
Jan 20 18:36:43 rpi4161a-172-101 kernel: [65880.245028] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: ****
Jan 20 18:36:43 rpi4161a-172-101 kernel: [65880.248227] cdc_acm 1-1.3:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
Jan 20 18:36:43 rpi4161a-172-101 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 13: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Jan 20 18:36:43 rpi4161a-172-101 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 13 was not an MTP device
```

- Checking if the raspberry pi was overheating, using `vcgencmd`. It returns `8000 Soft temperature limit has occurred` flag sometimes, but not always.
- Tried the following method to "reset" the serial connection, which had no effect

```
 echo -n '1-1.3:1.0' | sudo tee -a unbind
 echo -n '1-1.3:1.0' | sudo tee -a bind
```

- Followed some of the solutions here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9264/how-do-i-reset-a-usb-device-using-a-script, including the solution to reset the USB bus, with no luck.

Comment: You may have a flaky/unreliable/broken USB adapter.  Have you tried a different one?  And the least you could do is provide more details.

Comment: Thank you @sawdust! I added a little more context and other things we tried, however, I was unfamiliar with how to even start debugging USB serial disconnections, which is why I wanted to start with a clean slate here. Other than what I tried above, where exactly can I look to see what kind of errors would be reported if it is a faulty adapter?

Comment: how often (second? minute?) is the periodic disconnection? happened under some specific operation or random?

Comment: @SuPra how are you powering your Raspberry Pi? This could also happen due to insufficient rating/quality of used power adapter.

Answer (score 2):

USB Serial malfunctioning may be caused by many different factors, including software, hardware or noisy environment.

The following diagram roughly describes the related components,

```
  --------------------      ----------------
  | Userspace (Apps) |      | Power Supply |
  --------------------      ----------------
        ^
        |
  --------------------      -------------       ----------
  | Kernel (Drivers) |  <-- | USB Cable |  <--  | Device |
  --------------------      -------------       ----------
```

### Narrow down to the faulty part

As first step, elimination method can help us to narrow down to the faulty part, basically you replace the suspect part with another good component, and observe if it changes result. for example,

- use the latest official raspbian image to eliminate userspace issue
- choose a different kernel/firmware image to eliminate kernel/driver issue
- change usb cable
- change usb device
- use a decent power supply

### Troubleshooting on software issue

Assume we could narrow down the scope to software, I would use the following procedures to do further check,

1. Make sure the usb device is recognized by kernel, check with `lsusb`, `dmsg`, `udevadm`.
2. Have a correct name (dev path), check udev rules;
3. Run `udevadm monitor` to observe any unexpected disconnection events, make sure it works (stable connection) on a fresh OS image, and install only necessary packages step by step.

### Other tips

- Check if your usb device is a "smart" device? meaning the device may have its own logic to disconnect or change mode, so that affect your host side connection.

Answer (score 0):

To see what happened on the USB bus it is better to use usbmon (see https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB).
I think you should carefully ***check usb descriptors***: `lsusb -v` and check ***how much current it attempts to take*** (check configuration descriptor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-configuration-descriptors).
I think reconnects could occur ***due to insufficient current to you usb device*** especially if device supplied only from bus. If current > than usb host controller can provide, usb host-controller limits current this could lead to device reset. To check this hypothesis connect your device to `Raspberry` using `active hub with external power supply`.